# The first law of Thermodynamic in curved space

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

As we know, the first law of thermodynamic is $ dE=TdS-PdV+\mu dN $.  is it true for a generic metric? what is the covariant form of this equation? for example, I think chemical potential and number density will be corrected as follow: 
\begin{equation} 
\epsilon=Ts-P+A_{\mu}J^{\mu} 
\end{equation} 
where $A_{0}$ is chemical potential.